# Checking availability of data in columns of table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Iam having table TestTable where i have few columns say

```
            C1  | C2 | C3 | c4
            'ab'|  1 | 09 |          //CASE1 [ must return 1]
                |    |    |          //CASE2 [ must return 0]
```

I want to check if data in that table is present if any of columns data is present i want my value to be 1 , if all the columns are blank(No Data) then i want my value to be 0

Can any one help, i have no idea expect this condition in front of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try following query, using `COALESCE` command:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(C1,C2,C3,C4) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM TestTable
```

if Blank values are not actually NULLs but empty strings, query can be changed to:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN C1+C2+C3+C4 = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM TestTable
```

Or, probably the best variant, to check for both NULLs and empty strings:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(C1,'')+COALESCE(C2,'')+COALESCE(C3,'')+COALESCE(C4,'') = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM TestTable
```

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(id,name,temp) <>'' THEN 1 ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) end from Test.

Here only first column is considred even if i have values in second/third column iam not getting 0 as output where i must get 1

Comment: WHich ever the column i first is considered and second and others are neglected , i need condition to check all the columns values

Comment: This way its working

SELECT CASE WHEN coalesce(id+name+temp,'') <>'' THEN 1 ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) end from test

Comment: Can you please edit your ans with these, saying your ans as case1 and these as case2

Comment: @þÍńķ Updated. You should have stated in question that 'no data' are actually empty strings and not NULLs and what are the column data types.